# Hyperledger Fabric Nix Derivation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, nix

I'm trying to build a nix derivation for the Hyperledger Fabric project.

source root is source

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "hyperledger-fabric";
  src = builtins.fetchGit {
    url = "https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric";
    rev = "d0eaa0646fc83bf17066a82f54b3c99370914a02";
  };

  depsBuildBuild = [curl which git];
  nativeBuildInputs = [go docker];
}
```

when running `nix-build fabric.nix` I receive:

```
nix-build fabric.nix
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/8z0wlnf8897ng5wkfjja66m31fafsqyp-hyperledger-fabric.drv
building '/nix/store/8z0wlnf8897ng5wkfjja66m31fafsqyp-hyperledger-fabric.drv'...
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/q4mq48i1f7sp7d8f3n8w6q8kp053h9ny-source
source root is source
patching sources
configuring
no configure script, doing nothing
building
build flags: SHELL=/nix/store/n9hba031gjky8hpjgx9fnlaxhidyzxbz-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash
gotools.mk:22: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
builder for '/nix/store/8z0wlnf8897ng5wkfjja66m31fafsqyp-hyperledger-fabric.drv' failed with exit code 2
error: build of '/nix/store/8z0wlnf8897ng5wkfjja66m31fafsqyp-hyperledger-fabric.drv' failed
```

The error points to https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/gotools.mk#L22

Do I need to set environment variables or what is causing the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by use of `buildGoPackage`, see https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/52551